# Send data with OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl

For testing, i want to create 2 SSL* instances and let them send data to each other.

After the handshake is complete i can send data from the client to the server without any problem.
Sending data from the server to the client fails, with the this error: **'error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac'**

The following code is used for sending data in both cases, the SSL* instances are based on memory BIOs, error checks have been removed for readability.

```
SSL* source;
SSL* destination;
BIO *r_bio;
BIO *w_bio;
int sRc;

//....    

r_bio = SSL_get_rbio(destination);
w_bio = SSL_get_wbio(source);

//Encrypt message 

printf("Buffer before encryption: %d Bytes -> 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x...\n", _g_buffer_lenght, _g_buffer[0], _g_buffer[1], _g_buffer[2], _g_buffer[3], _g_buffer[4]);

ERR_clear_error();
sRc = SSL_write(source, _g_buffer, _g_buffer_lenght);
if (sRc <= 0) {
    _log_openssl_error_queue();
    return -1;
}

_g_buffer_lenght = BIO_ctrl_pending(w_bio);
BIO_read(w_bio, _g_buffer, _g_buffer_lenght);

printf("Buffer after encryption: %d Bytes -> 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x...\n", _g_buffer_lenght, _g_buffer[0], _g_buffer[1], _g_buffer[2], _g_buffer[3], _g_buffer[4]);

//Decrypt message 

BIO_flush(r_bio);
BIO_write(r_bio, _g_buffer, _g_buffer_lenght);
ERR_clear_error();
sRc = SSL_read(destination, _g_buffer, _g_buffer_lenght);
if (sRc <= 0) {
    _log_openssl_error_queue();
    return -1;
}

_g_buffer_lenght = sRc;
printf("Buffer after decryption: %d Bytes -> 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x...\n", _g_buffer_lenght, _g_buffer[0], _g_buffer[1], _g_buffer[2],    _g_buffer[3], _g_buffer[4]);
```

The record that is produced after encryption looks correct (right type, version and length).

Is there some extra step needed when sending data from server to client, i would expect the 2 peers to be equal once the handshake is complete?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem.

My test code let the instances exchange data till both return 1 for **SSL_is_init_finished**, the problem was that the client instance returns 1 after it has sent its TLS_FINISHED but it still needs the servers TLS_FINISHED message to be able to communicate.